# Testing a Function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a test to verify that a function is called when the page is loaded.  I am trying to spyon it but its saying that it does not exist.

Could someone please give me some help on how to properly spy on it?

Here is the angular code:

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('uotc')
    .controller('reportGroupArchiveCtrl', ReportGroupArchiveCtrl);

ReportGroupArchiveCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$q'];

function ReportGroupArchiveCtrl($scope, $http, $stateParams, $q) {
    $scope.reportType = $stateParams.reportType;
    $scope.templateTypeId = $stateParams.templateTypeId;
    $scope.group = $stateParams.group;

    //Initialize the page
    activate();

    function activate() {
        //Call the API to get the generated reports for this group
        $http.get('api/url/params....)
            .then(getGeneratedReportsComplete)
            .catch(apiCallFailed);
    }

    function getGeneratedReportsComplete(data, status, headers, config) {
        //do stuff
    };
    function apiCallFailed(e) {
        return null;
    }
}
})();
```

Here is the test:

```
describe('Controller', function () {
var stateparams, controller, scope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('uotc'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
    stateparams = { reportType: 'Vendor', templateTypeId: 2, group: 'VENDOR_1' };
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    controller = _$controller_('reportGroupArchiveCtrl',{
        $scope: scope,
        $stateParams:stateparams
    });
    spyOn(controller, 'getGeneratedReportsComplete')

}));

describe('is loaded', ()=> {
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        $httpBackend
            .when('GET', 'api/url/params)
            .respond(200, '123')
        $httpBackend.flush();

    }));
    it('calls the generated reports API', ()=> {
        expect(controller.getGeneratedReportsComplete()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

});

Comment: @deltree Function declarations in JavaScript are hoisted to the top, so that should be fine. The actual problem is that it's a local.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
    expect(controller.getGeneratedReportsComplete()).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This is better:

```
    expect(controller.getGeneratedReportsComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You pass the function itself to `expect`; you shouldn't call it.

The other problem is that `getGeneratedReportsComplete` is declared as a local variable inside the constructor, so it's not accessible outside that, and you cannot spy on it. Instead, define it on the `this` object:

```
this.getGeneratedReportsComplete = (data, status, headers, config) => {
    //do stuff
};
```

Of course you need to call it as `this.getGeneratedReportsComplete` as well.

Comment: Hey - Thanks for the response.  I did this and not im not even getting into my getGeneratedReportsComplete function.  Any ideas?

$http.get('....').then(this.getGeneratedReportsComplete)
                .catch(apiCallFailed);
...
this.getGeneratedReportsComplete = function (data, status, headers, config) { //stuff }

Comment: You need to assign it before you use it: `this.getGeneratedResponseComplete = ...;` and only then do `$http.get(...)`.

Comment: so when i put the this.getGeneratedResponseComplete function inside the activate() method it calls the method.  But the spy still does not see the method. "Error: getGeneratedReportsComplete() method does not exist"